# R package installation with GitHub

Tags: github, repository, r-package

I am trying to install the package "PITE" as it is mentioned in the codes used in the article "Subgroup Identification Clinical Trials via the Predicted Individual Treatment Effect". The codes are taken from "https://github.com/nicoballarini/PLOS-2018-PITE#subgroup-identification-clinical-trials-via-the-predicted-individual-treatment-effect". But I'm unable to load this package, it would be very helpful if anyone can tell me where am I going wrong? The error message that I get:

```
install_github("nicoballarini/PLOS-2018-PITE")
Downloading GitHub repo nicoballarini/PLOS-2018-PITE@master
✓  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/ml/wj8v_nld19n52l2g3tvzmltr0000gn/T/RtmpD4r8z6/remotes186f6614c26d/nicoballarini-PLOS-2018-PITE-832e47b/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘PITE’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘PITE_0.1.0.tar.gz’

* installing *source* package ‘PITE’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘broom’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘broom’ could not be loaded
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘PITE’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/PITE’
Error: Failed to install 'PITE' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/ml/wj8v_nld19n52l2g3tvzmltr0000gn/T//RtmpD4r8z6/file186f5ce8b676/PITE_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
Reason: image not found
```